# Using Stainless steel or iron pots in oven

Tags: circuits

Today I was using oven in my office with a plate of meal
the plate was made of stain less steel, my colleague rushed and asked me
to take it out otherwise the oven will be short circuit

So please inform me if S.L.Steel or iron pots are OK for the oven or
are they really harmful ?

Comment: Was it a microwave oven?

Answer (score 3):

If it was a microwave oven then **all metals** can [damage the oven](https://www.gizmodo.com.au/2014/05/what-actually-happens-when-you-put-metal-in-a-microwave/) if they are placed in the oven & the oven is operating.

If the oven is is thermal oven that is heated by an electric element, gas or wood, then there will no issues with using steel or stainless steel items in such ovens,

Comment: As sparse as the question is, everything points to microwave oven. Pretty common in offices due to low cost, easy cleanup, etc. Only one exception would be for a combination convection/microwave oven. Use with care!

Comment: As your link clearly states,  metal doesn't damage a microwave.  At all.  Particular shapes of metal might lead to a fire, which is a secondary mechanism.  I'm hard-pressed to imagine a pan, iron or stainless, with "pointy bits" on it.

Comment: And as long as I'm at it,  take some very fine steel wool (hey, it's steel!) and let it come in contact with an open flame or a glowing electrical heater element at that will catch fire.   So much for non-microwave oven safety.